# Chalkboard pre-recorded drawing in reveal presentation not loading

Tags: plugins, reveal.js

I have been using the chalkboard plugin for a reveal presentation. As it is written on the github page (https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/tree/master/chalkboard), I saved the drawings in a json file by pressing d (as far as I can tell, the data was correctly stored in the json file) and then I added the line `src: "prova/cb.json",` to the initialization for chalkboard and loaded the presentation with ?print-pdf.

However, when I open the presentation, there is no trace of the drawings that should be loaded.
This is the html of a minimal (non) working example...

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Prova</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/night.css" id="theme">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/monokai.css" id="highlight-theme">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">            
                <section >              
                <h4>Prova</h4>  
                </section>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/zoom/zoom.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/math/math.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/chalkboard/plugin.js"></script>

        <script>

            Reveal.initialize({
                hash: true,
                controls: false,
                transition: 'convex',
                math: {
                    mathjax: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js',
                    config: 'TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
                },

                 chalkboard: { 
                    src: "prova/cb.json", 
                    toggleChalkboardButton: { left: "80px" },
                    toggleNotesButton: { left: "130px" },
                },
                 plugins: [ RevealMarkdown, RevealHighlight, RevealNotes, RevealZoom, RevealMath, RevealChalkboard ],
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add syntax highlighting to the code? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help